# Notification system in Java

Tags: java, notifications

I am building an API for my system which receives UDP messages and parses them. Now I need to notify the developer, about those changes.

Currently I have 2 implementations in mind, but I am not sure which one is better and whether there are other options.

**Solution A** *ArrayBlockingQueue*

It seems it does not consume any power while idling. On API side I would just create a static array and add messages to it when I want to notify about new change. So on the developer side I could put it in a thread to listen for any new messages. The user would fetch the message, check its type and properties etc.

**Solution B** *Callbacks*

I believe this solution would be more beautiful and more organised. I simply create an interface with all possible notification types and then the developer can implement this interface. On the API side I have a hashmap of same listeners so that API can notify more than 1 same type listener.

Any more ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

For any event-based system an asynchronous solution is highly preferred. As you note, it is more lightweight than a blocking solution, which requires a thread *per each event receiver*. So, Solution B is favored.

One thing to be aware of, though, are threading issues: you will be calling the callbacks in your own thread, so the callback implementor must be prepared to deal with that. The callback code must not assume it is executed on any particular thread; it may as well be executed on a different thread each time.

Answer (score 2):

The [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern may be helpful to you, particularly if it is possible to have more than one listener for the same subject.

An alternative to defining a hashmap of listeners is to use a CopyOnWriteArrayList of listeners. With this approach, addition of new listeners doesn't interfere with iteration over listeners.

An alternative to defining an interface accepting all possible notification types is to define an interface with a single method accepting a root class or interface of all possible notification types. For example, this interface can recevie any event object subclassing the parameterized type EVENT.

```
public interface IObserver<EVENT> {
    public void receive( @NonNull EVENT event );
}
```

Comment: OP assumes *Observer* in his Solution B. "Callback" is virtually a synonym for "observer" in this context.

Comment: OP does not mention the Observer pattern. Knowledge of an existing pattern is at worst harmless, and may be useful.

Comment: I'll bet you five bucks he knows the patterns inside out!

Comment: Speculation. And the OP is not the only person reading these.